# Generating a dictionary of column names based on a condition among columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following data frame :

```
                        a_11        b_14    c_13     d_12
AC                      True        False   False   False 
BA                      True        False   False   True
AA                      False       False   False   False
```

I want a dictionary with key as the index and the values as the list of column names which have true values ie

```
{
AC : [a_11],
BA : [a_11,d_12],
AA : []
}
```

How am I supposed to proceed with this problem

#### edit : the column names are string, not a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictioanry comprehension if performance is important with transpose DataFrame and convert columns names to list:

```
d = {k: v.index[v].tolist() for k, v in df.T.items()}
print (d)
{'AC': ['a_11'], 'BA': ['a_11', 'd_12'], 'AA': []}
```

Another idea with `zip` and convert values to 2d numpy array by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
d = {k: df.columns[v].tolist() for k, v in zip(df.index, df.to_numpy())}
print (d)
{'AC': ['a_11'], 'BA': ['a_11', 'd_12'], 'AA': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) here to multiply `df` with `df.columns` then use [`df.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) to filter out empty strings `''`

```
out = df.mul(df.columns).agg(lambda x:[*filter(None, x)], axis=1)

AC          [a_11]
BA    [a_11, d_12]
AA              []
dtype: object
```

You can use *list comprehension* here.

```
vals = [df.columns[m].tolist() for m in df.values]
# vals -> [['a_11'], ['a_11', 'd_12'], []]
pd.Series(vals, index=df.index)

AC          [a_11]
BA    [a_11, d_12]
AA              []
dtype: object
```